# CloudFront decompress objects for viewers that don't support compression

Tags: http, amazon-cloudfront, content-encoding

I was looking at setting up an S3 origin with pre-compressed objects. This mostly work by setting the content-encoding on the object and CloudFront will forward the compressed object or even convert it from `gzip` to `br`.

However it appears to have a problem when the client doesn't support compression. In this case CloudFront will just return the compressed object anyways leading to effectively corruption.

Is there a way to make CloudFront decompress these objects for viewers that don't request/support compression? For example like the [nginx ngx_http_gunzip_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html)?

Comment: Does the pre-compressed object stored in S3 have the proper `content-encoding` header set?

Comment: It does, but that doesn't help if the client doesn't support that content-encoding. For example `curl example/index.html` will return the gziped version of `index.html`. You need to do `curl --compressed` so that curl decompresses it.

Comment: CloudFront does not decompress the objects in any time.